# Working with transform and mutate in tidyverse to calculate a cumulative sum

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, cumsum

When I try to calculate the cumulative sum of a variable using "mutate" I seem to get a new variable that is simply a replica of the original one. However, if I use "transform" instead of mutate, I get the right answer but one of my variable's column name is changed (from "2019" to "X2019") which I don't want.

I've replicated the problem below:

First using "mutate"

```
df1 <-  data.frame(Year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019), 
           Week = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2))

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Year, Week) %>% 
  count(name = "Cases") %>% 
  spread(Year, Cases, fill = 0) %>% 
  group_by(Week) %>% 
  mutate(Average = sum(`2016`, `2017`, `2018`)/3) %>% 
  select(Week, `2019`, Average) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative.2019 = cumsum(`2019`), 
         cumulative.Average = cumsum(Average))
```

Which produces this:

[image]

And now using "transform"

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Year, Week) %>% 
  count(name = "Cases") %>% 
  spread(Year, Cases, fill = 0) %>% 
  group_by(Week) %>% 
  mutate(Average = sum(`2016`, `2017`, `2018`)/3) %>% 
  select(Week, `2019`, Average) %>% 
  transform(cumulative.2019 = cumsum(`2019`), 
         cumulative.Average = cumsum(Average))
```

Which produces this:

[image]

My preference would be to do this with "mutate" as it doesn't change the column names. I've tried using rowwise() before the mutate line and I've tried group_by(Week), neither of which worked. Clearly I'm missing something here. Any help or advice would be most appreciated .

Comment: Remove the `group_by(Week)`?

Answer (score 2):

That is because your data is grouped which has an impact on `mutate` but not on `transform`. If you `ungroup` the data it works fine.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
 group_by(Year, Week) %>% 
 count(name = "Cases") %>% 
 tidyr::spread(Year, Cases, fill = 0) %>% 
  group_by(Week) %>% 
  mutate(Average = sum(`2016`, `2017`, `2018`)/3) %>% 
  select(Week, `2019`, Average) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(cumulative.2019 = cumsum(`2019`), 
         cumulative.Average = cumsum(Average))


#   Week `2019` Average cumulative.2019 cumulative.Average
#  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>              <dbl>
#1     1      0   1.67                0               1.67
#2     2      1   0.667               1               2.33
#3     3      1   0.667               2               3   
#4     4      1   0.333               3               3.33
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `ungroup()`

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Year, Week) %>% 
  count(name = "Cases") %>% 
  spread(Year, Cases, fill = 0) %>% 
  group_by(Week) %>% 
  mutate(Average = sum(`2016`, `2017`, `2018`)/3) %>% 
  select(Week, `2019`, Average) %>% 
  # error occurs here
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(cumulative.2019 = cumsum(`2019`), 
         cumulative.Average = cumsum(Average))
```